# <input type="file"> not working in webview

Tags: android, webview

So I am a HTML/CSS developer in a noob stage. Im trying to build a simple webview app for my website. Now while i got a project from github for webview it seems that the "File Upload" doesnt work in webview but works like a charm in browser. Help me please. Also if the app's whole intention is just converting website into android app and if you think there is a project on github that can be easy for my purpose (file upload in webview) then you can give me the link to it! Thanks!

My MainActivity.java:

```js
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;


public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private WebView mWebView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.activity_main_webview);

        // Force links and redirects to open in the WebView instead of in a browser
        mWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());

        // Enable Javascript
        WebSettings webSettings = mWebView.getSettings();
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

        // Use remote resource
        // mWebView.loadUrl("http://example.com");

        // Stop local links and redirects from opening in browser instead of WebView
        // mWebView.setWebViewClient(new MyAppWebViewClient());

        // Use local resource
        mWebView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/index.html");
    }

    // Prevent the back-button from closing the app
    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        if(mWebView.canGoBack()) {
            mWebView.goBack();
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As per your expectation, I think you want to enable heavy task in your WebView. For that you need to enable **ChromeClient**,

```
mWebView.setWebChromeClient(new MyWebViewClient());
```

And your MyWebViewClient class will be,

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.activity_main_webview);

        // Force links and redirects to open in the WebView instead of in a browser
        mWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
        mWebView.setWebChromeClient(new MyWebViewClient());    // HERE

        // Enable Javascript
        WebSettings webSettings = mWebView.getSettings();
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

        // Use remote resource
        // mWebView.loadUrl("http://example.com");

        // Stop local links and redirects from opening in browser instead of WebView
        // mWebView.setWebViewClient(new MyAppWebViewClient());

        class MyWebViewClient extends WebChromeClient {
            @Override
            public void onProgressChanged(WebView view, int newProgress) {
                super.onProgressChanged(view, newProgress);
            }
    
            @Override
            public void onReceivedTitle(WebView view, String title) {
                super.onReceivedTitle(view, title);
            }    
        }

        // Use local resource
        mWebView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/index.html");
    }
```

Comment: where should i paste it? the first line?

Comment: i pasted in MainActivity and WEbViewClient but i get loads of errors! ;-;

Comment: add : import android.webkit.WebChromeClient;

Comment: messed up! do you know any github project which supports the working of this issue! Thanks <3